# the number $x$ was drawn x from with uniform distribution of the integers {1,2,...,n} (n is unknown), what is n most likely to be?

Tags: probability

the number $x$ was drawn from with uniform distribution of the integers ${1,2,...,n}$  ($n$ is unknown), what is n most likely to be?

intuition tells me its $x$, if that's true the probability of it being chosen would be $\frac1n = \frac1x$, any other possible value would be higher then $x$ would result in a smaller probability that $x$ was be chosen.

is that a valid argument?

Comment: The question is not well-posed.  It doesn't make sense to say "what is the most likely value of $n$? (given some observation)" unless you have prior knowledge or assumptions about the distribution of $n$.  Note especially that there is no uniform distribution on $\mathbb N$ so you can't just say "they're all equally likely" which is what your argument presumes.

Comment: Let me put it this way, since as the above comments are pointing out, it's not so cut and dried.  If you want to calculate the maximum likelihood estimator amongst the distributions you can select from, then yes that is a valid argument to calculate it.

Comment: i know that there is no uniform distributions on the natural numbers, but if i you drew the number 5, or 8293, without knowing the maximum number that can be drawn, isn't there anything constructive we can deduce from what we know about n? (except the it must be at least x...)

Comment: I think to nail down your question you need to define a notion of what statistic your estimator should optimize.  e.g. If $\hat{N}$ is your choice of $n$ given the one outcome, perhaps you would like to minimize the variance of $\hat{N} - N$ where $N$ is the true length of the distribution.

Comment: Your intuition is correct. The maximum likelihood estimate of $n$ is $x$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Discrete_uniform_distribution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called the [German Tank Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem). In the case when the sample size is $1$ and the datum is $n$, the best estimate is $2n-1.$

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me in order to put this question on the most solid ground you need a prior distribution on $n$ to make this work, and ideally a proper prior distribution (i.e. a real-valued distribution over the integers whose sum is 1). Just doing maximum likelihood to determine $n$ is equivalent to using an improper prior, specifically uniform over the set of positive integers (so the probability of each integer is identical and basically zero but somehow the probabilities all add up to 1, which is impossible but we pretend it's true). A proper prior distribution is much more satisfying than this. For example, with a proper prior you can come up with a confidence interval for $n$, but this is impossible with the improper "uniform" prior I described. If your prior distribution probability values are decreasing in $n$, then you will still get the result that the most likely value of $n$ is the value that you sampled. The difference is that now the result will be much more well-founded.